# Docker-Compose with multiple services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

THIS IS A SAMPLE QUESTION! NEVER DO IT IN PRODUCTION. RUN NGINX / PHP / OTHER SERVICES IN SEPARATE CONTAINERS!

When I start `docker-compose up` the Ubuntu container exits with `ubuntu exited with code 0`.

When I run `docker run -d -ti -p 80:80 -v ~/sph/laravel52:/www/laravel ubuntu`, all works fine.

How can I replicate this behavior using Docker Compose?

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Version: 0.0.1
FROM ubuntu:15.04



ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

#INSTALL ALL
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
       nano \
       php5-fpm \
       php5-mysql \
       nginx



#NGINX CONF
ADD nginx/sites-available/laravel.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN mv /etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

VOLUME /www


ENTRYPOINT nginx && service php5-fpm start && /bin/bash

CMD ["true"]


EXPOSE 80
```

And `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
        build: .
        container_name: ubuntu
        volumes:
            - ~/sph/laravel52:/www/laravel
        ports:
          - "80:80"
```

Comment: I understand you may do this in purpose `ENTRYPOINT nginx && service php5-fpm start && /bin/bash`. But if you don't understand implication of that decision you could read the following https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker

Comment: Img name. My error. Ubuntu

Comment: I had a similar issue in adding ruby into a centos Dockerfile. So I used  'RUN yum update && yum install -y ruby'

Answer (score 241):

The thing is that you are using the option `-t` when running your container.

Could you check if enabling the `tty` option (see [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/cpushares-cpuquota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-macaddress-memlimit-memswaplimit-privileged-readonly-restart-shmsize-stdinopen-tty-user-workingdir)) in your docker-compose.yml file the container keeps running?

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
        build: .
        container_name: ubuntu
        volumes:
            - ~/sph/laravel52:/www/laravel
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        tty: true
```

Comment: Did you get an error message: `ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.` after you added `tty: true`?

Comment: tty works because it creates a pseudo terminal. I had a similar problem with SQL Server 2017 container. It was running fine in standalone mode but was exiting in the docker-compose mode for multi-container scenario. Here is what I did with tty to fix it https://www.handsonarchitect.com/2018/01/docker-compose-tip-how-to-avoid-sql.html

Comment: @NileshGule thanks for your time to explain why tty works, however, I'd like to know a little more, if you don't mind. How exactly creating a pseudo terminal will prevent from exiting? Thanks again.

Comment: @LuisMilanese generally when the foreground process completes within the docker container, it assumes that the job is completed and cleans up the container instance. But things like Database engine and web servers need to continue running. By creating a pseudo terminal the container remains alive. You can see this workflow by running the docker logs <<container name>> command with and without tty

Comment: tty is not working for me.. i am  using version "3" of docker-compose