# use cloudera with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cloudera

when i use cloudera with docker like that :

```
docker run -it cloudera/quickstart:latest /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

Everything works fine, i can't use it, and access to the ui via DOCKER_IP:50070

but, if i want to add cloudera to a docker-compose file, like that :

```
version: '2'
services:
  cloudera:
    image: cloudera/quickstart:latest
    command: /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
    ports:
      - "8020:8020"
      - "8022:22"     # ssh
      - "7180:7180"   # Cloudera Manager
      - "8888:8888"   # HUE
      - "11000:11000" # Oozie
      - "50070:50070" # HDFS REST Namenode
      - "2181:2181"
      - "11443:11443"
      - "9090:9090"
      - "8088:8088"
      - "19888:19888"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "8983:8983"
      - "16000:16000"
      - "16001:16001"
      - "42222:22"
      - "8042:8042"
      - "60010:60010"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
```

Nothings works and the container stop directly after launching.
Here is just the end of the stacktrace for information :

```
cloudera_1  | Starting Solr server daemon:[  OK  ]
cloudera_1  | Existing PID file found during start.
cloudera_1  | Removing/clearing stale PID file.
cloudera_1  | Started Impala Catalog Server (catalogd) :[  OK  ]
cloudera_1  | Started Impala Server (impalad):[  OK  ]
hadoopmongokafka_cloudera_1 exited with code 0
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue es pretty similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100358/docker-composer-exited-with-code-0/37103967#37103967).

Could you check if adding the `tty: true` field to your docker-compose the issue solves?

```
version: '2'
services:
  cloudera:
    image: cloudera/quickstart:latest
    command: /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8020:8020"
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this as well:

```
version: "2"
services:
  cloudera:
    image: cloudera/quickstart:latest
    command: /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
    privileged: true
    hostname: quickstart.cloudera
```