# Cant get my python app to start in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have the following python code:

```py
from data_pipeline.scraper_processor import ScraperProcessor


def main():
    print("Welcome to The Main function")
    sp = ScraperProcessor()
    sp.parse_message()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where ScraperProcessor is the following class:

```py
from data_pipeline.Account import Account
from typing import List
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


class ScraperProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        self._consumer = KafkaConsumer('test',bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
```

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5-alpine3.9
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
CMD ["python","main.py"]
```

and the following docker compose file:

```
  version: '3.1'

  services:
    postgres_db:
      image: postgres
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: admin
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
        POSTGRES_DB: default_db
      ports:
        - 54320:5432
    zookeeper:
      image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
    kafka:
      image: wurstmeister/kafka
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    parse-engine:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - "kafka"
        - "postgres_db"
```

I have all three files - Dockerfile,docker-compose file and the main.py file in the root directory of my project, however when I run the whole thing with `docker-compose up` the postgres_db and the kafka server seem to go up as expected but the dockerized python container exits immediately:

```
leumiprocessor_parse-engine_1 exited with code 0
```

Could you please help me understand what im doing wrong here?

Comment: If Kafka isn't running would this line cause an exception?:
`self._consumer = KafkaConsumer('test',bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')`
My guess is that Kafka isn't up yet. Putting it in `depends_on` doesn't mean that docker compose will wait until Kafka is running, it will wait until that container has started.

Comment: use `wait-for-it.sh` or add `time.sleep(60)` in your python code, you can check also with `docker logs container_name`

Comment: Hmm though I still dont see any of my prints in the docker logs {CONTAINER_ID} of the parse-engine container

Comment: The first python file that contains function `main`- is the file name "main.py"?

Comment: What does `parse_message` on `ScraperProcessor` look like? If it doesn't block on receiving a message, the program will terminate. Without further information, it appears that the Python program is just running to its exit normally.

Comment: Could you run the parser container by it self? `docker build .. & docker run`. The you could do `docker exec -ti <container_name> /bin/bash` to login to the container and check whats going on. BTW how do you pass the `host` & `port`  values of the database to you're service?

Answer (score 0):

> leumiprocessor_parse-engine_1 exited with code 0

seems like there is no error from the application, as container exit with code `0`. something wrong with `CMD` or `docker-compose`. Or might be the case your main.py run and die after completion, to make your containers up and running the main process should be running, so

> Could you check if enabling the tty option (see reference) in your
>   docker-compose.yml file the container keeps running?

```
    parse-engine:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - "kafka"
        - "postgres_db"
      tty: true
```

[Docker-Compose exited with code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100358/docker-compose-exited-with-code-0)

Or you also try to specify CMD in compose file

```
    parse-engine:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - "kafka"
        - "postgres_db"
      command: "python main.py"
```

The life of `CMD` or `entrypoint` is the life of the container, so in case if your python script dies after running the container, the container will ultimately die.